# Setting variable is not being set up during testing middleware (p

Tags: django, pytest

**settings.py**

```
MY_VAR = os.get("MY_VAR", False)
```

**custom_middleware.py**

```
from my_proj.settings import MY_VAR
from django.core.exceptions import MiddlewareNotUsed


class CustomMiddleware:
    def _init_(self, get_response):
        if MY_VAR == 'False':
            raise MiddlewareNotUsed
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if MY_VAR == 'True':
            #My custom logic
            return 
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

**test_custom_middleware.py**

```
import os from unittest.mock import Mock
from api.middlewares.custom_middleware import CustomMiddleware


class TestLCustomMiddleware:
    def test(self, settings):
        request = Mock()
        settings.MY_VAR = 'True'
        assert settings.MY_VAR
        with patch.dict('os.environ', {'MY_VAR': 'True'}):
            assert 'MY_VAR' in os.environ
            middleware = CustomMiddleware(get_response='response')
            middleware(request)
```

In `CustomMiddleware` I always get `"False"` in `MY_VAR` variable of settings. How can I set it up?

**Updated**.

Thanks to Philippe and Dharman.
It works fine

**custom_middleware.py**

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import MiddlewareNotUsed


class CustomMiddleware:
    def _init_(self, get_response):
        if settings.MY_VAR == 'False':
            raise MiddlewareNotUsed
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if settings.MY_VAR == 'True':
            #My custom logic
            return 
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

**test_custom_middleware.py**

```py
from api.middlewares.custom_middleware import CustomMiddleware
from django.test import override_settings

class TestLCustomMiddleware:
    @override_settings(MY_VAR="True")
    def test(self):
        request = Mock()
        middleware = CustomMiddleware(get_response='response')
        middleware(request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code), you should import your setting using :

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.MY_VAR:
    # Do something
```

"django.conf.settings" isn’t a module, it’s an object. So importing individual settings is not possible. This example below won't work properly :

```
from django.conf.settings import MY_VAR
```

Furthermore, it's not recommended to [change setting during Runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime) :

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.DEBUG = True   # Don't do this!
```

Instead you should try using [override_settings()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) or [modify_settings()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.modify_settings).
For example :

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

class TestLCustomMiddleware(TestCase):

    @override_settings(MY_VAR=True) # without quote
    def test(self):
        ...
```